# Manga with an assassin with eyes that can kill

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find a manga I've read before. It's about a pair of assassins/mercenaries/hired killers (by their company).

- protagonist can kill someone just by looking at them
- his partner's personality resembles a (stray) dog's (male)
- protagonist has black hair, his partner has blond/light hair
- they met when they were children and fought each other and adults that where searching for the partner
- partner was "stolen" from his rich family by a dog (wolf) and was raised by it.
- the partner was homeless as a child but got food from the homeless old people
- the protagonist tried to quit once but was threatened

In the first chapter they jump off a building onto a car (after a crash?) at night. They kill their target but a bystander sees them and faints and is taken to the hospital. Not knowing what to do they take him with them until they get confirmation on whether to kill him or not.

Answer (score 2):

Could the manga you're searching for be [Get Backers](https://myanimelist.net/anime/132/GetBackers)

> The series tells the story of Ginji Amano and Ban Mido, a pair of super powered individuals known as the "GetBackers". The duo operates a freelance repossession service out of one of the seedier areas of Shinjuku, Tokyo. For a fee, they will recover any lost or stolen item for a client with "an almost 100% success rate". The GetBackers' job often leads them into bizarre and dangerous situations in order to "get back what shouldn't be gone". Their targets range from lost video games to misplaced components of an atomic bomb. The plot mostly revolves around their adventures, often complicated by the pair's convoluted, individual pasts and a mysterious place known as the Infinity Fortress.

The two protagonists Ginji Amano and Ban Mido

[image]

The blond one has electric powers and the dark haired one has enhanced strength and magic eyes that create illusions.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: While I first thought of this same manga, I remembered that Ban's "Evil Eyes" doesn't kill the victims...

Comment: @RebekahWall I saw the same question in another forum and the answer given was B-Eyes.

Comment: @Subbies B-Eyes sounds like a solid match from the first chapter on. Post it as a new answer :)